# Problems on select module on Python 2.5

Tags: python, macos, beanstalkd

I have an application in Python 2.5 that listens to a beanstalk queue. It works fine on all machines I tested so far, except from my newly acquired MacBook Pro.

On that computer, when I try to run it I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jobs.py", line 181, in <module>
    Jobs().start()
  File "jobs.py", line 154, in start
    self.jobQueue = Queue()
  File "src/utils/queue.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.connection = serverconn.ServerConn(self.server, self.port)
  File "src/beanstalk/serverconn.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.poller = select.poll()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'poll'
```

The serverconn.py has the following imports:

```
import socket, select
```

And when I try to run it from command line, it fails as well:

```
Python 2.5.1 (r251:54863, Jul 23 2008, 11:00:16) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5465)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import select
>>> select.poll()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'poll'
```

Do you have any idea on what can be happening?

PS: Even though I am pretty confident it's not a source problem, if you need some background on the source that's failing, it's available at [http://pastie.org/399342](this pastie).

*Updated:* since the first answer I got speculates whether select.poll() is or not supported on Mac OS, but I have an iMac too and with the exact same OS version and it works fine:

```
2009-02-25 00:27:10,067 - Queue - DEBUG - Connecting to BeansTalk daemon @ localhost:11300
```

Comment: could you add 'osx' tag? i do not have enuf rep to do myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) version of `python` on your MBP.

Mac OS X supports this.  Apple stock Leopard `python 2.5.1` does not.

you will want to download and install MacPorts if you have not already.  FYI, I find [Porticus](http://porticus.alittledrop.com/) to be an excellent GUI around MacPorts.

here is a comparison of stock Leopard python vs. latest MacPorts python2.5...

---

Leopard python from Apple (python 2.5.1) - **`select.poll()` broken**

```
$ /usr/bin/python
Python 2.5.1 (r251:54863, Jan 13 2009, 10:26:13) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5465)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socket, select
>>> select.poll()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'poll'
>>>
```

Macports (python 2.5.4) - **`select.poll()` works!**

```
$ /opt/local/bin/python2.5
Python 2.5.4 (r254:67916, Feb  3 2009, 21:40:31) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5488)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socket, select
>>> select.poll()
<select.poll object at 0x11128>
>>>
```

Answer (score 6):

According to [this macports ticket](http://trac.macports.org/ticket/18376) Apple's implementation of poll() is straight up broken.  Apple worked around this by disabling poll() in Python and macports now disables poll in their Pythons as well.  I think this means you need to look into Python's select.kevent() instead of poll on mac.

Answer (score 2):

I think your answer is here

http://atomized.org/2008/12/python-on-os-x-leopard-lacks-selectpoll/

Answer (score 0):

[**select.poll()**](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html?highlight=select#select.poll)

(*Not supported by all operating systems.*) Returns a polling object, which supports registering and unregistering file descriptors, and then polling them for I/O events; see section Polling Objects below for the methods supported by polling objects.

My guess is that it's not supported on the macOS.

Comment: monkut, thanks for you response but not the case - I have an iMac where it runs just fine... :( That makes me more intrigued.

Comment: Ok, looks like JMP is pointint you in the right direction.  Good luck resolving your issue!

Comment: Thanks monkut, I think that I have installed 2.5 on my other mac using MacPorts... Go figure...